# how to select data from database based created_at today in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, time, days

how to select data from database based created_at today in rails?

example :

```
[#<Event id: 1, customer_id: 1, therapist_id: 1, location_id: 1, service_id: 3, walkin: true, cancel: false, cancel_reason: nil, room_id: 5, starts_at: "2014-04-03 21:31:13", stops_at: nil, created_at: "2014-04-14 10:13:52", updated_at: "2014-04-14 10:13:52">, #<Event id: 2, customer_id: 2, therapist_id: 2, location_id: 2, service_id: 2, walkin: false, cancel: false, cancel_reason: nil, room_id: 1, starts_at: "2014-04-05 21:31:13", stops_at: nil, created_at: "2014-04-14 10:13:52", updated_at: "2014-04-14 10:13:52">, #<Event id: 3, customer_id: 1, therapist_id: 2, location_id: 1, service_id: 1, walkin: false, cancel: false, cancel_reason: nil, room_id: 5, starts_at: "2014-04-07 21:31:13", stops_at: nil, created_at: "2014-04-14 10:13:52", updated_at: "2014-04-14 10:13:52">, #<Event id: 4, customer_id: 2, therapist_id: 2, location_id: 2, service_id: 2, walkin: false, cancel: false, cancel_reason: nil, room_id: 1, starts_at: "2014-04-09 21:31:13", stops_at: nil, created_at: "2014-04-14 10:13:52", updated_at: "2014-04-14 10:13:52">, #<Event id: 5, customer_id: 14, therapist_id: 2, location_id: 2, service_id: 1, walkin: true, cancel: false, cancel_reason: "", room_id: 8, starts_at: "2014-04-15 06:47:00", stops_at: "2014-04-15 07:47:00", created_at: "2014-04-15 06:47:14", updated_at: "2014-04-15 06:47:14">]
```

and when i collect data based created_at today i get result :

```
<Event id: 5, customer_id: 14, therapist_id: 2, location_id: 2, service_id: 1, walkin: true, cancel: false, cancel_reason: "", room_id: 8, starts_at: "2014-04-15 06:47:00", stops_at: "2014-04-15 07:47:00", created_at: "2014-04-15 06:47:14", updated_at: "2014-04-15 06:47:14">
```

how to collect all data where data created_at just today in rails?

thanks before

Answer (score 6):

Please try this:

```
Event.where("DATE(created_at) = DATE(?)", Time.now)
```

Answer (score 1):

To fetch today's `events`, it will return only `today's` events

```
Event.where("created_at = ?", Date.today)
```

Here's what I have tried in my console

```
2.0.0p247 :008 > Article.where("created_at < ?", Date.today)
  Article Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` WHERE (created_at < '2014-04-15')
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Article id: 2, title: "Villa Kerylos: A Greek Dream.. A Modern Villa", description: "An inside look at one of the Mediterranean's most i...", url: "http://frenchantiques.blogspot.com/2009/05/villa-ke...", is_open_in_new_window: true, created_at: "2013-12-26 07:03:17", updated_at: "2013-12-26 10:28:36">, #<Article id: 4, title: "Kenzo Auctions Personal Art Collection", description: "Kenzo Auctions Personal Art Collection", url: "http://frenchantiques.blogspot.com/2009/06/kenzo-au...", is_open_in_new_window: false, created_at: "2013-12-26 09:57:21", updated_at: "2013-12-26 09:57:21">]>
```

Comment: This can't be working, as he has a Time-Object for his created_at.

Comment: It is working, you can test it at your end, please don't down vote without reason.

Comment: Ok. YOu are right. 
I have tried it with usual ruby-code:
`if Time.now>Date.today puts "true" else puts "false" end`.
It didn't work. I'm sorry, for having bisvoted your post.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a try with this code.

```
Event.where("created_at >= ? and created_at <= ?", Time.now.beginning_of_day, Time.now.end_of_day)
```

Comment: There is no such function `beginning_of_day` in the normal Time-class

Comment: @user3383458 Check this link http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-beginning_of_day

Comment: @RSB I have checked Time.now.beginning of day. It returns ``<main>': undefined method `beginning_of_day' for 2014-04-15 12:47:24 +0200:Time (NoMethodError)`... This function is for **DateTime**

Comment: `2.0.0p247 :018 > Time.now.beginning_of_day

# => 2014-04-15 00:00:00 +0530`

Comment: @user3383458, `Time.now.beginning_of_day` should work.. It's strange that it is not working on your end.

Answer (score 0):

`Event.where("created_at > ?" Time.now.to_date.to_time)` should work, because you want todays entries. Also, a good Idea, is those of the last 24 hours, which should be `Event.where("created_at > ?-60*60*24 and created_at < ?" Time.now)`

Answer (score -1):

```
Event.where('created_at >= ?', Date.today)
```

Maybe you can parse the created_at to the same short format and compare, but this should be enough.